# bitand : keyword vs function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I've tried using the alternative bitwise operator 'bitand' in below simple code. Its appears that I can use bitand as a keyword as well as a function in Visual C++, both yielding different results, can anyone explain this discrepancy?

```
int d = 12, e = 37;
std::cout << (d & e) << std::endl; //4
std::cout << (d bitand e) << std::endl; //4
std::cout << *bitand(d, e) << std::endl; //37
int* bit_and = bitand(d, e);
std::cout << *bit_and << std::endl; //37 (should it be 4?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite appearances, `bitand(d, e)` is not invoking a function named `bitand` and passing it the arguments `d` and `e`. `bitand` is just [another way of spelling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) `&`.

So your code is actually identical to `&(d, e)`. `&` isn't a function, so what's the comma doing here? It is the lesser-known [built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). It evaluates and discards the first argument, then evaluates and returns the second argument. So `(d, e)` is the same as `e`, and your code boils down to `&e`.

So despite the code saying `bitand`, there's no bitwise and happening here. It's acting as the unary [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) and returning a pointer that points to `e`. That's why you have to dereference it with unary `*`, and why the value after dereferencing is `37` not `4`.

---

As an aside, if you're using clang or gcc, if you enable `-Wunused` (which is included in `-Wall`), the compiler will issue a warning that you're discarding a value with no effect, like so:

```
<source>:8:26: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    8 |     std::cout << *bitand(d, e) << std::endl; //37
      |
```

Which would have given you a heads-up that this wasn't acting like a function invocation but instead something else.

Answer (score 0):

`bitand` is the keyword in C++, equivalent of `operator &` with the identical behaviour, taking a single or double arguments depending on usage context.

```
*bitand(d, e)
```

is identical to

```
*&(d, e)
```

The result of the comma operator in the parentheses is a reference to the last variable

```
*&e
```

Getting the addresses of the variable and dereferencing obviously returns the variable value.